# Controlled input stream reading with rxjava

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

Trying to read some csv file with jackson CSV mapper and since the file is large in size, planning to parallelize reading and processing it in a fixed memory environment which is far less than the file. So the process must be pipelined.

What I tried is as follows:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("//some large file");
ObjectReader reader = CSV_MAPPER.readerFor(Test.class).with(schema);
JsonParser jsonParser = CSV_MAPPER.getFactory().createParser(fis);
Iterable<Test> iterable = () -> reader.readValues(jsonParser);

Flowable.fromIterable(iterable)
        .buffer(1000)
        .observeOn(Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_POOL)))
        .subscribe(saveBatchToDb);
```

However above code finishes after about 120 iterations. I know `Flowable`'s default buffer size is 128. **But at the first place, why would i ever need backpressure when subscribers requests items?** I checked jackson's internals (readValues method), it advances input stream when `iterator.next` is called, so i think this reading process should be controllable by downstream. Also used `observeOn` for multithreading downstream (saveBatchToDb).

**My Assumption**
When any of my executor threads is finished, it would pull items from upstream and process those items and so on. In this case, I can both parallelize the process and hopefully fit THREAD_POOL * 1000 * [Test object size] bytes into memory easily.

For every document about rxjava I have read so far, states that `Flowable` is preferable over `Observable` in processing large number of items because it supports **backpressure**. I cannot simply relate the backpressure and and controllable flow. Also when I replace `Flowable` with `Observable`, JVM immediately halts throwing oom as expected.

A simple while loop plus some partitioning code can be perfectly enough for that task, but I'm wondering how it would work with reactive way with rxjava. What are the key points behind? What is wrong with my assumptions?

Comment: Recommended reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#parallel-processing